# Setup wifi programatically using WPA Security in android tablet

Tags: android, android-layout

I am trying setup WiFi programatically on an Android tablet. If there is no WiFi connection then add the network with SSID and passkey read from a text file. Adding this network to network list and saving the passkey. It's adding the network and saving the passkey also but when I try to connect, it's not connecting. let me know...

```
public static void setupWifi(Context _context)
{
     if(deviceConfig.wireless_ssid.length()==0) return;

     WifiManager wifi = (WifiManager)_context.getSystemService(_context.WIFI_SERVICE);
     WifiConfiguration wc = new WifiConfiguration(); 
     wc.SSID = "\"" + deviceConfig.wireless_ssid + "\""; //IMP! This should be in Quotes!!
     wc.hiddenSSID = true;
     wc.status = WifiConfiguration.Status.ENABLED;     
     wc.priority = 40;
     wc.allowedKeyManagement.set(WifiConfiguration.KeyMgmt.WPA_PSK);
     wc.allowedProtocols.set(WifiConfiguration.Protocol.WPA);

     wc.allowedAuthAlgorithms.set(WifiConfiguration.AuthAlgorithm.OPEN);

     wc.preSharedKey = "\"" + deviceConfig.wireless_passkey + "\"";// 

     Log.d("ssid : ", wc.SSID );

     List<WifiConfiguration> netWorkList =  wifi.getConfiguredNetworks();
     WifiConfiguration wifiCong = null;

     if (netWorkList != null) {
         for(WifiConfiguration item:netWorkList) {
             if (item.SSID.equalsIgnoreCase("\"" + deviceConfig.wireless_ssid + "\"")) {
                 wifiCong = item;
             }
         }
     }

     if (wifiCong == null) {
         boolean res1 = wifi.setWifiEnabled(true);
         int res = wifi.addNetwork(wc);
         Log.d("WifiPreference", "add Network returned " + res );
         boolean b = wifi.enableNetwork(res, true);   
         Log.d("WifiPreference", "enableNetwork returned " + b );  
         boolean es = wifi.saveConfiguration();
         Log.d("WifiPreference", "saveConfiguration returned " + es );
     }
 }
```

Thanks
Kiran

Answer (score 3):

I had this problem as well.  The way I solved it was manually adding the wifi network to the device.  I then enumerated over the configuration and copied the values that the device added to successfully connect to that network.

To clarify:

Add the network by hand, call the network manager to get the configured networks, find your network, and then call the getters out of everything you are trying to set - you will find the exact configuration you need.

```
void getWifiConfigs()
{ 
    WifiManager wifi = (WifiManager) getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE); 
    List<WifiConfiguration> networks = wifi.getConfiguredNetworks();
    for (WifiConfiguration current : networks){
        //check getters here
    }
}
```

Comment: what if the configuration is not saved on the device at all?

Comment: @tasomaniac the application will get crash due to nullPointerException,So call this within try catch block.