# Android using wifimanager to connect to WPA-PSK secured network

Tags: android, wifi, wifimanager, wpa

so I have trawled true all threads in here and any where else where google would take me. But still I am having problems connecting to WPA PSK networks.
Here is my code, I have 2 edittext fields from which I read SSID and PSK and then one checkbox to select if SSID is hidden or not.

```
    EditText mSSID = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.wifiTVssidcurrent);
    String networkSSID = mSSID.getText().toString();
    EditText mWPA = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.wifiTVwpacurrent);
    String networkWPA = mWPA.getText().toString();

    // Update text to show that connection is pending
    TextView wifiStatus = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.wifiTVconnectionstatus);
    wifiStatus.setText("Connecting to " + networkSSID);

    WifiManager wifi = (WifiManager) getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE); 
    WifiConfiguration wc = new WifiConfiguration(); 
    wc.SSID = "\"".concat(networkSSID).concat("\""); 
    wc.preSharedKey  = "\"".concat(networkWPA).concat("\"");

    CheckBox mSSIDHidden = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.wifiCBhiddenssid);
    wc.hiddenSSID = false;
    if (mSSIDHidden.isChecked()) {
        wc.hiddenSSID = true;
    }
    wc.status = WifiConfiguration.Status.ENABLED;         
    wc.allowedGroupCiphers.set(WifiConfiguration.GroupCipher.TKIP); 
    wc.allowedGroupCiphers.set(WifiConfiguration.GroupCipher.CCMP); 
    wc.allowedKeyManagement.set(WifiConfiguration.KeyMgmt.WPA_PSK); 
    wc.allowedPairwiseCiphers.set(WifiConfiguration.PairwiseCipher.TKIP); 
    wc.allowedPairwiseCiphers.set(WifiConfiguration.PairwiseCipher.CCMP); 
    wc.allowedProtocols.set(WifiConfiguration.Protocol.RSN);
    int res = wifi.addNetwork(wc); 
    Log.d("WifiPreference", "add Network returned " + res ); 
    boolean b = wifi.enableNetwork(res, true);         
    Log.d("WifiPreference", "enableNetwork returned " + b );
    boolean c = wifi.reconnect();
    Log.d("WifiPreference", "reconnect returned " + c );
```

What I see in the phone after running this is that an AP is created in settings, but it is not connecting. And if I try to use the created AP manually from settings afterwards I am not able to connect either.
But if I create the AP from within settings I get connection as I should.

As for putting SSID and WPA PSK in I have tried both "\"".concat(networkSSID).concat("\"");  and "\""+ networkSSID +"\""; with same result.

Any tips will be very welcome.
Best regards
Lasse

Comment: So I thought I had tried everything suggested here on stack overflow.
But this thread actually helped me in the end
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8392747/setup-wifi-programatically-using-wpa-security-in-android-tablet
So big thanks to RYAN for providing the tips on reading one AP and then mimmick it.
In my case it turned out that I needed to add

Even though I am setting up for WPA I still needed to add
allowedGroupCiphers WEP40 and WEP104
And I only had
wc.allowedProtocols.set(WifiConfiguration.Protocol.RSN);
So I also added
wc.allowedProtocols.set(WifiConfiguration.Protocol.WPA);

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Again big thanks to Ryan for proposing how to read the settings created by the OS.

So I thought I had tried everything suggested here on stack overflow. 
But this thread actually helped me in the end [Setup wifi programatically using WPA Security in android tablet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8392747/) So big thanks to RYAN for providing the tips on reading one AP and then mimmick it. In my case it turned out that I needed to add Even though I am setting up for WPA I still needed to add allowedGroupCiphers WEP40 and WEP104 And I only had

```
`wc.allowedProtocols.set(WifiConfiguration.Protocol.RSN); //So I also added 
 wc.allowedProtocols.set(WifiConfiguration.Protocol.WPA);`
```