# Is it possible to "lazy" connect to WiFi network?

Tags: android, networking

What I want to do is maybe not possible but I'm asking just in case.

I use `List<ScanResult> sr = mWiFiManager.getScanResults()` to find (in the list) a network that I can identify by its SSID.

Now I know that this network exists and is up and running. It is *always* secured with WPA2.

Knowing the SSID, I would like to be able to activate it then connect to it.

I would also like to see the Android password dialog to popup if the network has not been set yet. This is the case when connecting for the first time.

I though that, given the SSID, I could start an `Intent` but is doesn't seem to be that simple.

The problem is that in all examples I found, the password was given when activating the network. See [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9725830/android-using-wifimanager-to-connect-to-wpa-psk-secured-network?rq=1) for example.

So, is it possible to do what I want to do (under Android 4.0+)?

Thanks for your help!